# How to get the ID if condition is met in multiple table

Tags: mysql

i've tables like

**personal info:**

```
uid name   location relation
12  ario   32       1
13  arvin  32       4
```

**Professional Info**

```
uid inst   pos
12  SER    admin
13  Wipro  data analyzer
```

now, how to get the **uid** who works in Wipro, with relation of 4 (which is 13)

Comment: Try something even if it`s not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from `personal info` p inner join `Professional Info` pi 
on p.uid = pi.uid
where p.relation = 4
```